# Get last value of selected row in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

**I am trying to automatically find the last column in the current row with values. I want to do this because some rows have more columns than others.** Here is the

Spreadsheet I am taking data from

[image: 1].

Here is the query I have right now. I am getting circular dependency issues.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("redacted_link","PriceList!A1:AZ100000"), "Select "&IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,(INDIRECT("R[0]C1", FALSE)):(INDIRECT("R[0]C50", FALSE))))&" where Col1 = '"&(INDIRECT("R[0]C1", FALSE))&"'",1)
```

This part: `where Col1 = '"&(INDIRECT("R[0]C1", FALSE))&"'",1)` already works and is effective at getting the value of column 1 in the current row.

```
&IFERROR(LOOKUP(9^9,(INDIRECT("R[0]C1", FALSE)):(INDIRECT("R[0]C50", FALSE))))&
```

I think this is referencing the current file instead of the [spreadsheet I am taking data from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bX3J9.jpg).

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE(
 "id", "PriceList!A1:AZ100000")),,9^9))), "\d+(?:.\d+)?")*1)
```